# MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine in MainActivity.java in Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I'm trying to call a few methods from native android Java files to Flutter. In my `MainActivity.java` file i am getting the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
                                           ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

This is the code in the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper";
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if (call.method.equals("helloFromNativeCode")) {
                  String greetings = helloFromNativeCode();
                  result.success(greetings);
                }
              }});
  }
private String helloFromNativeCode() {
    return "Hello from Native Android Code";
  }
}
```

Given below is my Flutter code that I'm calling in my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Native Code from Dart'),
      ),
      body: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('flutter.native/helper');
  String _responseFromNativeCode = 'Waiting for Response...';
  Future<void> responseFromNativeCode() async {
    String response = "";
    try {
      final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('helloFromNativeCode');
      response = result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      response = "Failed to Invoke: '${e.message}'.";
    }
    setState(() {
      _responseFromNativeCode = response;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Call Native Method'),
              onPressed: responseFromNativeCode,
            ),
            Text(_responseFromNativeCode),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement something similar to what is given [here](https://medium.com/47billion/creating-a-bridge-in-flutter-between-dart-and-native-code-in-java-or-objectivec-5f80fd0cd713).
I've tried various ways to call this however I haven't been able to.

Comment: What is you flutter code? Check the [flutter.dev guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: Ive edited the question could you please have a look?

Comment: Check the `imports` in `MainActivity.java` once,
on flutter.dev  they are `import androidx.annotation.NonNull;`
`import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;`
`import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;`
`import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;`

Answer (score 0):

The error is usually thrown when the Android build has issues compiling after upgrading the Flutter SDK. A quick workaround here is to regenerate the Android build by deleting the `/android` folder and generating a new one by running `flutter create --platforms=android` on the terminal.